# Matplotlib displaying RGB pixels weirdly

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pixel, rgb

I have a set of RGB pixels I gathered from an image, but when I try to save them and display them, they come out very weirdly, as 3 separate colors. It seems like it's not reading my array as a list of RGB values.

I have an abbreviated version of my code, with a short list of RGB values:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [127, 255, 127], [239, 255,  15], [127 ,  0,   0]])

plt.imshow(img)
plt.savefig('testtt.png', dpi=400)
```

which gives me this:
[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve this or what might be wrong? Or alternatively, if anyone knows a better way to display RGB pixels from an array, please let me know. Side note: I am trying to avoid OpenCV

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: [This example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-image-demo-py) makes use of the interpolation parameter. Did you try that?

Comment: [Interpolating Images](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo.html#interpolating-images)

Comment: [Axes.imshow](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow).

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2D array will be interpreted as values to be color mapped. That's why you see 4 rows of 3 colors.

To interpret the array as 4 rgb values, you can plot a 3D array:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.array([[255, 255, 255], [127, 255, 127], [239, 255, 15], [127, 0, 0]])
plt.imshow([img]) # note the extra brackets
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.imshow with rgb values]

To illustrate what was happening with the original plot, seaborn's heatmap can automatically add some annotations and a colorbar.

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(img, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='viridis')
plt.imshow([img])
```

[image: sns.heatmap of intended rgb array]

PS: To display RGB values as an `NxM` array of pixels, the values should form a 3D `NxMx3` array:

```py
img = np.array([[[255, 255, 255], [127, 255, 127]], [[239, 255, 15], [127, 0, 0]]])
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: a 2x2x3 array]

Comment: This is right, but I think it's a little mysterious to put the extra brackets outside the np.array.  What the OP wants is a MxNx3 array, or in this case 1xNx3.  OP: please see the docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html

Comment: Other options, `img[None,...]`, `img.reshape(1,4,3)`.

Comment: Do any of you know how to reshape the data so I can display it differently? I have more data than this, and I would rather not have to view it only in a straight line

Comment: I added an extra example.  You can also just change the dimensions: `plt.imshow(img.reshape(2,2,3))` (when `img = [[255, 255, 255], [127, 255, 127], [239, 255, 15], [127, 0, 0]]`).  The dimensions need to fit exactly.  You can use `-1` for one of the dimensions, to let Python calculate that last dimension, e.g. `img.reshape(-1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you created an array of lists

```
img = np.array([[255, 255, 255],[127, 255, 127],[239, 255,  15],[127 ,  0,   0]])
```

But nothing tells python to treat this as and RGB image, so instead it created an array with four rows and three columns. Then when you plotted it here:

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

It simply applied colors from the viridis color pallet and displayed it as a visual array where each value got a color from that pallet.

As mentioned in the comments, you need to expressly tell python to treat this array as an image:

```
imshow(img, origin='upper', interpolation='nearest')
```

For a straight pixel-by-pixel translation